# Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a]’

Tags: haskell

I have this list in which I want to go through and convert certain elements of the list into a string. The first 3 functions work, however, the last one (placeRainfull) does not. When I try to load the script, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Place’ with actual type ‘[Place]’
```

I want the function to go through each element in the list and have it run through the addDayWithRainfull function.

**Code**

```
getRainfull :: Place -> (String, [Int])
getRainfull (Place p _ _ rf ) = (p, rf)

convrtIntArray :: [Int] -> [String]
convrtIntArray rainfullArray = map show [ i | i <- rainfullArray]

addDayWithRainfull :: (String, [Int]) -> String
addDayWithRainfull (p, rf) = p ++ " " ++ unwords (convrtIntArray rf)

placeRainful :: [Place] -> String
placeRainful places = addDayWithRainfull (getRainfull places)
```

Comment: How did you define `Place`?

Comment: Please include the full error. There should be information about where exactly the error occurred.

Comment: `getRainfull` is defined for `Place` and not for `[Place]`.

Comment: in `placeRainful`, `getRainfull` is applied to `places` which is a `[Places]` where `getRainfull` expects a `Place`... you shoud map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined a function:

```
getRainfull :: Place -> (String, [Int])
```

which takes as input a single `Place` object, but in your `placeRainful` you write:

```
placeRainful :: [Place] -> String
placeRainful places = addDayWithRainfull (getRainfull places)
```

so here you expect to process a *list* of `Place`s, that will not work. You can for example make use of [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) to process each `Place` in the list of places and then concatenate these together:

```
placeRainful :: [Place] -> String
placeRainful places = concatMap (addDayWithRainfull . getRainfull) places
```

or with [**`[a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate):

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

placeRainful :: [Place] -> String
placeRainful places = intercalate "," (map (addDayWithRainfull . getRainfull) places)
```

or perhaps you need to use some other function, but the general idea is that you will need something to pass *elements* of the list to `getRainfull`, not the entire list itself.

Comment: Are you able to show me an example of how to use the ``` intersperse ``` function instead of the concatMap

Comment: @UnknownPerson: you likely want to use `intercalate`, otherwise it will return a list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You've told the compiler that `placeRainful` takes a list of `Place`s (`[Place]`), but then you're passing that list of places to `getRainFull`, which you have indicated takes only a single `Place`.

In other words, Haskell is inferring based on the implementation of `placeRainful` that it should have type `Place -> String`, but then you said that that's not it's type.

As a side note, based on this several similar questions you've asked, it seems like you're having trouble differentiating the types `[Place]` and `Place`. Haskell (and indeed, most programming languages) cares a great deal about this distinction. Think about the data that each type represent:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] :: [Int]

1 :: Int
```

These types need to be treated differently because it's very clear what `a` should be in this expression:

```
let a = 1 * 1
```

but it's not at all clear what it should be in this expression:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3] *  [1, 2, 3]
```